# Cannot convert from subclass to superclass in Vector<Superclass>

Tags: java, inheritance, vector

I have a generic game class called `RiverCrossingGame`. The idea is that subclasses of this one will implement different river crossing puzzles.

In my superclass I have a `Vector` of states. Now these states are generic. The `GenericState` implements some behavior common in the concept of state for any river crossing game. The the subclass associated State will implement additional methods which are particular of the game.

So I have my `RiverCrossingGame` with the vector of states:

```
public abstract class RiverCrossingGame implements PuzzleGame {
    public GenericBank westBank;
    public GenericBank eastBank;
    public static Vector<GenericState> states;
    public List<String> steps;

    public abstract void play();
    public abstract void printSteps();
}
```

Then the `WolfGoatCabbageGame` I have defined a particular state for this game called `State`(it is in the Wolf, Goat and Cabbage game package) which is a subclass of the `GenericState`:

```
public class State extends GenericState {
    // State members...
}
```

Then in the class for the actual class I try to initialize the vector of states:

```
public class WolfGoatCabbageGame extends RiverCrossingGame {
    public enum Element { FARMER, WOLF, GOAT, CABBAGE };

    public WolfGoatCabbageGame() {
        westBank = new Bank("WEST", new Element[]{ Element.FARMER, Element.WOLF, Element.GOAT, Element.CABBAGE }, false);
        eastBank = new Bank("EAST", true);
        states = new Vector<State>();
        steps = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // more members...
}
```

And here's the problem. When initializing `states` I am getting this error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Vector to
>   Vector

And here's where this got me. `State` is a subclass of `GenericState`. Why wouldn't I be able to initialize the `Vector` that way? Am I missing something obvious? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to initialize `states` as `Vector<GenericState>`. Once it's been initialized, you can populate it with instances of type `State`, as they are instances of the `GenericState` class.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing :) I was confused because for I moment I was afraid since they would be `GenericState` instances the `State` methods wouldn't be find. Then I realized I was wrong and they wouldn't be `GenericState` instances but `State` instances as I add them.

Comment: Glad that worked! If you feel like it makes sense, you should consider "Accepting" this answer.

Comment: I know, but there's a timer and I cannot upvote right now. As soon as I can I will.